# Replacement for NeDB for consistant, replicated persistent node.js data storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nedb

I have a node.js server application that stores it's data (small, as in "few kb") in [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb). I need to have more than one instance with synchronized data. As NeDB was not designed to handle replication I need an alternative persistent data storage. Main requirement is consistency between instances.

[MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) seems to be obvious choice as [NeDB implements subset of MongoDB API](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#api), but spinning up a Mongo cluster just to handle few kilobytes of data seems to be excessive.

**What are replicating, strongly consistent persistent data storage alternatives (for few kilobytes of data), preferably with NeDB-compatible API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert, but perhaps CouchDB/PouchDB may help you out? DBs specifically designed for replication. However, not sure about the NeDB-compatible API requirement.

Comment: I actually did go with CouchDB to handle thisbproblem. Sadly, API is based on different approach and is nowhere near compatible. I'm accepting this answer as "lesser evil".